# Android > Google Maps > Overlay: Tap different things to make different things happen

Tags: java, android, google-maps, overlay, itemizedoverlay

I am trying to make an app where when the user taps on a blank part of the map, a new flag appears, and then when they tap the flag, a dialog box appears.

I wrote the first onTap method on my own, and copied the second from the Google Maps tutorial to get myself started.  The problem is, the first one always fires and the second one never does.  If I delete the first method, the second one works as it's supposed to (tapping a flag makes its corresponding dialog appear).  These are both methods in an ItemizedOverlay class, mContext is the context generated by the constructor, and locations is an ArrayList of OverlayItems.

My question is, how can I reconcile the two?

```
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView){
        locations.add(new OverlayItem(p, "Point 3", "Point 3"));
        populate();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = locations.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by implementing/overriding `onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)` you are preventing `ItemizedOverlay`'s own implementation of that method from running which itself would normally call `onTap(int index)`.

You want something more like...

```
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView){
    if (super.onTap(p, mapView)) 
        return true; 

    locations.add(new OverlayItem(p, "Point 3", "Point 3"));
    populate();
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = locations.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant.  So here's what I'm getting:

ItemizedOverlay is the Overlay of just the little pictures of the flags, whereas the class I defined blankets the entire map.

So when the user taps, Android first checks if the user tapped somewhere in the ItemizedOverlay (by the way, the only nitpick is that it's super.onTap, not super(onTap)) and if they did, it skips ahead to the other onTap method (dialog box) and if they didn't it makes a new flag.

Comment: The one question I still have is:  Previously, if I tapped on a flag, the dialog box wouldn't come up but instead it would make a new flag behind it.  I assumed that this was because the method to make the dialog box pop up was overridden, but it seems like it still is within the framework.  Could you explain a little more clearly what's happening to make that no longer the case?  I also don't really understand why super.onTap(p, mapView) would return true if the user tapped on a flag.
Thanks!

Comment: `onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)` is the method declared in `Overlay` which will be called by the `MapView` in response to a touch event. `ItemizedOverlay`'s implementation of this method contains logic to map the given `GeoPoint` to an existing `OverlayItem`. If an `OverlayItem` is found it calls your `onTap(int index)` implementation and returns whatever that returns. If it can't locate an item it returns false. So by returning true from `onTap(int index)` you are stopping a new item being added in you `onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)` implementation. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I still don't get why previously it wasn't showing a dialog when I clicked on an existing 'OverlayItem'.  Based on what you said, if I'm interpreting it correctly, wouldn't I expect it to show the dialog and then make a new flag?

Comment: No, because previously you were not calling through to the superclass and your `onTap(int index)` method never got called.

Comment: Gotcha.  So calling through the superclass in the new line calls onTap(int index), and if this returns true then nothing happens (return true).  So I noticed that the line is super.onTap(p, mapView) instead of super.onTap(index), does it go from the first to the second somehow?

Comment: Yes, the super class implementation calls `onTap(index)`.